# How can I sort arrays of various sizes in Java? Like 10, 20, 50, 100, 1000 Elements?

Tags: java

I need to sort arrays of varying sizes. These sizes are: 10 elements, 50 elements, 100 elements, 500 elements, and 1000 elements. For each of these array sizes, I should use one array that is already sorted, another array that is partially sorted, and one that is random. I should use three sorts, like quicksort, insertion, or bubblesort. I have been working this for 2 weeks but can not seem to create an call the arrays.

Comment: So what is that you need help with?

Comment: this smells a lot like homework...

Comment: you can go and use the utility functions provided by java like Arrays.Sort() , also you can see what they have implemented and similar implementations can be done on your part

Comment: Let's see every single line of your code. Also, what is the exact issue you're having when "calling" the arrays?

Comment: What I am trying to do is sort the Elements 10, 50, 100, 500, 1000. My problem is how can I create a list or class to call those elements, so I can use them in my 3 sort functions. I will post some code I have:

Comment: Random r = new Random();
  int arr[] = new int[50];

  for(int i = 0; i < 50; i++){
     //partial numbers from 1 to 50:
     arr[i] = Math.abs(i+(int)(Math.random()*(double)10)-5)%50;
  }

  for(int i = 0; i < 50; i++){
     System.out.print(arr[i] + " ");
  }

Comment: My problem is how to call the separate Integers or Elements of 10,20,50,100, 500, 1000. I need sort those elements. So I am trying to figure out how to input that into my code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are some utility methods to create test arrays and to verify if your sorting method is working fine:

```
public static Integer[] createRandomArray(int size) {
    Integer[] result = new Integer[size];
    Random randomGenerator = new Random();
    for(int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        result[i] = randomGenerator.nextInt(size*100);
    }
    return result;
}

public static Integer[] createSortedArray(int size) {
    return createPartiallySortedArray(size, 0, size);
}

public static Integer[] createPartiallySortedArray(int size, int from, int to) {
    Integer[] result = createRandomArray(size);
    Arrays.sort(result, from, to);
    return result;
}

public static boolean isSorted(Integer[] original, Integer[] sorted) {
    Integer[] clonedOriginal = Arrays.copyOf(original, original.length);
    Arrays.sort(clonedOriginal);
    return Arrays.equals(clonedOriginal, sorted);
}
```

Note - the `from` and `to` parameters have to be in the range `[0..size-1]` with `from < to`.

---

Here's fragment that you can use to create your arrays, feed them into your sorter and verify the results:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<Integer[]> arrays = new ArrayList<Integer[]>();
    int size = 100;
    arrays.add(createRandomArray(size));
    arrays.add(createPartiallySortedArray(size, 0, size/2));
    arrays.add(createSortedArray(size));

    List<Integer[]> result = doBubbleSort(arrays);  // <- implement that method
    for (int i = 0; i < arrays.size(); i++)
        System.out.println(isSorted(arrays.get(i), result.get(i)));
}
```

Comment: FTW! This should make the rest super easy.

Comment: public class ArrayTwo {
 
 { 
  
  Random r = new Random();
  int arr[] = new int[50];

  for(int i = 0; i < 50; i++){
     //partial numbers from 1 to 50:
     arr[i] = Math.abs(i+(int)(Math.random()*(double)10)-5)%50;
  }

  for(int i = 0; i < 20; i++){
     System.out.print(arr[i] + " ");
 I am trying to create the set of arrays, maybe in one Class and let the sorts call to the one ArrayList. I have tried ArrayLists, but I can not seem to build it.

Comment: My problem is how to call the separate Integers or Elements of 10,20,50,100, 500, 1000. I need sort those elements. So I am trying to figure out how to input that into my code.

Comment: `array[0]` is the first element of the array, `array[array.length-1]` the last one. Spend a minute or two with a Java tutorial on arrays.

Comment: I have spent 2 weeks in the tutorials, online, viewing arrays, code, etc. I still have not seen any demo of quicksort, bubblesort, or others that have shown the int size as "selectable" so I can insert the other elements in one set of code. How do I make the int size change with out writing a block of code for each element I want to sort.

Comment: I know once  I initialize an array in java like "int size=100;" that it is set. That is why I was trying to learn about array lists or vectors. So I could add.element. My problem is that, creating the list so I can call each element of integers. So I could sort(element) if then next.element. But I can not locate any viable references or I am looking in the wrong places.

Comment: @ Andreas_D I will try to work with the sample code you posted for the List<Integer> and see if I can create the elements I need. Thanks for your help.

Comment: arrays can't resize - you create one array with a fixed size (say: 100), then populate it with values, like I did in the `createRandomArray` method. If you want to swap values, you *read* them from the array and *write* them back at (new) positions.

Comment: Yes I understand arrays don't re-size. So working with the elements from 20, 50, 100, 500, 1000. I would make my int size = 1000, then use for (int i =0; i < arrays.size(); i++) and another argument to call elements 1-500 to be sorted? I am trying write 1 class file and extend the 3 separate sort programs. Maybe I am out of my league on this one.